# Mongo DB Date Difference and and query condtion in same query in Java Mongo Template

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework

Hi guys i trying to make query like following

update date more than 2 hours, then status=inprogress get all tasks. 
query sample date is

```
{
    "_id" : "ATK-l64KC3vm",
    "nodeid" : "NOD-AJaodNfH",
    "accountid" : "d983356b-7fde-4683-9ba5-e6b6f5a0680d",
    "applicationid" : "59a57cb7-7d67-4d55-bd6c-ff537bcf05d6",
    "avmdepid" : "DEP-1aa81899",
    "instanceId" : "INS-YNXr1ldB",
    "cloudinstanceid" : "",
    "inputxml" : "",
    "status" : "No value present",
    "callbackUrl" : "",
    "callbackMethod" : "PUT",
    "callbackInput" : "<input></input>",
    "priority" : "false",
    "type" : "datapush",
    "createdDt" : ISODate("2020-05-20T05:56:55.467Z"),
    "updatedDt" : ISODate("2020-05-20T05:56:55.478Z"),
    "agentid" : "IAG-R2koJqnk"
}
```

pls help to make this query in java Mongo template aggregation filter

Comment: Can you please add sample document data in the question, and what output you are expecting

Comment: @PuneetSingh thanks for the reply, now I updated with proper information, pls help me out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we can use `$addFields` or `$set` to add new field (temporary) to document which will hold time difference. (in milliseconds)

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
  {"$addFields": {"timeDiff": { $subtract: [new Date(), "$updatedDt"]}}}
]);
```

Now, we will use those fields to filtering records using `$match`

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
 {"$addFields": {"timeDiff": { $subtract: [new Date(), "$updatedDt"]}}},
 {$match: {"timeDiff":{ $gte: 2* 60* 60* 1000},"status":"in-progress"}}
]);
```

Now, we can remove additionally added field using `$project`

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
 {"$addFields": {"timeDiff": { $subtract: [new Date(), "$updatedDt"]}}}, 
 {$match:{"timeDiff":{$gte: 2* 60* 60* 1000},"status":"in-progress"}},
 {$project: {"timeDiff":0}}
]);
```